# Comparing TIMEDIFF in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have these following data:

```
ID   TIMEIN                 TIMEOUT
1    2016-08-24 20:44:00    2016-10-22 19:35:36
2    2016-08-24 20:58:00    2016-08-24 20:59:09
```

and the following query that I want to use to find all the entries where the timediff is lesser than 50 hours

```
SELECT TimeDiff(TimeOut,TimeIn) 
from table where TimeDiff(TimeOut,TimeIn) < '50:00:00'
```

The second row should be returned because it's lesser than 50 hours, but the first row, which the timediff is more than 50 hours keep returning as well.

```
02:04:57
15:10:49
125:00:25
```

It returns all sort of value, including those larger than 50

What query should I be using? Thank you

Comment: Your output does not appear to match your sample data, i.e. there are three rows in the output and only two sample data rows and the none of the values from the output match what you would expect after applying `TIMEDIFF()` to the sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try getting the difference in hours and then comparing.

```
SELECT TimeDiff(TimeOut,TimeIn) 
from table where HOUR(TIMEDIFF(endDate, startDate)) < 50
```

Comment: select a,b,c,
     a > 24,
     b > 24,
     b > 24,
     a > '24:00:00',
     b > '24:00:00',
     b > '24:00:00',
     a > '0.24:00:00',
     b > '0.24:00:00',
     b > '0.24:00:00'
    from (
    select 
     TIMEDIFF('2020-01-31 22:00:00', '2020-01-31 00:00:00') a,
     TIMEDIFF('2020-02-02 00:00:00', '2020-01-31 00:00:00') b,
     TIMEDIFF('2020-02-01 22:00:00', '2020-01-31 00:00:00') c
    ) t


Using TIMESTAMPDIFF is best solution.

Answer (score 6):

Please use the following:

```
SELECT id,
       timeIn,
       timeOut,
       TIMEDIFF( timeOut,
                 timeIn ) AS timeDifference
FROM table
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( SECOND,
                     timeOut,
                     timeIn ) > 180000;
```

This statement will output the fields for each record where the difference between the two timedates is one second or more over `50 hours` (or `180000 seconds`).

Comment: While the selected answer is totally correct for the presented use case, I prefer this one, because it is more general in cases where you require a comparison with fractal hour values.

Comment: AND there is a PitFall: TIMEDIFF and TIMESTAMPDIFF produce an inversed sign, when the arguments are presented in the same order.